# Chrome Developer Tools scroll problem

Tags: google-chrome

I am working on a Front-end project and need to inspect elements (naturally). When doing that chrome's DevTools show me a page that has larger width than the view port with no apparent reason (a scroll bar appears in the bottom of the page and all).
When running the project on Mac everything works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using the rotate option might help.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and after changing some option in the preview panel/device toolbar panel one option worked out for me which is **Device Type**.

When I switched to responsive view the default view is **Mobile** and I changed that to **Desktop** which worked for me and when I switched back to Mobile the issue didn't appear again.

Although it did appear again after reopening the responsive view. This was not a permanent fix.

[image: Device Type option in the preview panel SS]

#### One observation

I think this issue is only for websites whose body height and width property is set to viewport height(vh) and viewport width(vw) respectively. Not sure if you were using the same properties or if not this then it might be just in the development environment.
Not sure about this but that's all I found out.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using Ubuntu corrently but I'm sure this info is helpful

Comment: Thanks so much. Was not using vh or vw, but it happened to me. I had to first "show device type", which was not the default, then select either Desktop or "mobile (no touch)" for it to work again